# string.lower() in contents.lower() not working correctly

Tags: python

My function looks up WHOIS requests using sockets and proxies.

Sometimes there is an issue with a proxy and it returns no data so I check to see if the data contains the initial domain request and if it does, return the result.

However sometimes this returns TRUE even when there's nothing in the string data.
I have also tried to do len(data) > 25, etc but for some reason it can still return true.

```
        if domain.lower() in data.lower():
            obj = WhoisEntry(domain, data)
            logger.debug('WHOIS success ' + domain + ': ' + data)
            return {
                        'expiration_date':  str(obj.expiration_date),
                        'status':           str(obj.status),
                        'registrar':        str(obj.registrar)
                   }
```

**Full code**

```
def whois_tcp(domain):
whois_servers = [ 'whois.verisign-grs.com', 'whois.internic.net', 'whois.crsnic.net' ]

attempts = 0

while attempts < 15:
    attempts = attempts + 1
    logger.debug('WHOIS attempt '+domain+': '+str(attempts))
    whois_host = random.choice(whois_servers)
    proxy = random.choice(proxies) # global variable from config.py
    proxy = proxy.split(':')

    try:
        s = socks.socksocket()
        s.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxy[0], int(proxy[1]))
        s.connect((whois_host, 43))
        s.send(domain + '\n\r\n')

        data = ''
        buf = s.recv(1024)
        while len(buf):
            data += buf
            buf = s.recv(1024)
        s.close()

       #if domain.lower() not in data.lower():
       #    raise Exception(domain, 'Domain not found in WHOIS: '+data)
       #    continue

        if domain.lower() in data.lower():
            obj = WhoisEntry(domain, data)
            logger.debug('WHOIS success ' + domain + ': ' + data)
            return {
                        'expiration_date':  str(obj.expiration_date),
                        'status':           str(obj.status),
                        'registrar':        str(obj.registrar)
                   }
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error('WHOIS Lookup Failed: '+str(e))
return None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing in `data`? How do you know?

Comment: I can view the data in: `logger.debug('WHOIS success ' + domain + ': ' + data)`

It's coming up blank: `DEBUG - WHOIS success able.org: `

Comment: do we have any example data

Comment: trim the data and check ! if there are spaces in data .it might consider

Answer (score 0):

1.Try:

```
if str(domain).lower() in str(data).lower():
    ...
```

2.Check whether the value of domain variable is None or ''.

Comment: Thanks, I have typecasted them as strings and I can view in the debug log file the domains are in fact correct and not None or any singular chars.

Still getting the same issue :(

Comment: Check the value str(domain).lower() and str(data).lower(). BTW, what is the version number of python ?

Answer (score 0):

I added code to write each whois response to file and noticed that it was in fact including whois results

```
    file = open('./whois_records/'+domain, 'w')
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
```

Not sure why this line of code wasn't outputting the data string in the log file:

```
logger.debug('WHOIS success ' + domain + ': ' + str(data))
```

I have found that different whois servers are giving me different results for lookups.

For example: **bpi-group.com**

```
  1. whois.verisign-grs.com: **FREE**
  2. whois.gandi.net: **TAKEN**
```

Additionally I need to use different whois server for different TLDs (com/net/org/info/biz)

Currently now using:

- **tld**.whois-servers.net

Code is still not perfect but is working better and **original problem has been solved**:

```
def whois_tcp(domain):
    ext = tldextract.extract(domain)
    if ext.suffix == 'org':
        whois_servers = [ 'org.whois-servers.net' ]

    elif ext.suffix == 'biz':
        whois_servers = [ 'biz.whois-servers.net' ]

    elif ext.suffix == 'info':
        whois_servers = [ 'info.whois-servers.net' ]

    elif ext.suffix == 'com':
        whois_servers = [ 'com.whois-servers.net' ]

    elif ext.suffix == 'net':
        whois_servers = [ 'net.whois-servers.net' ]

    else:
        whois_servers = [ 'whois.verisign-grs.com', 'whois.internic.net', 'whois.crsnic.net' ]

    attempts = 0
    result = None

    while attempts < 15:
        attempts = attempts + 1
        logger.debug('WHOIS attempt '+domain+': '+str(attempts))
        whois_host = random.choice(whois_servers)
        proxy = random.choice(proxies) # global variable from config.py
        proxy = proxy.split(':')

        try:
            s = socks.socksocket()
            s.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxy[0], int(proxy[1]))
            s.connect((whois_host, 43))
            s.send(domain + '\n\r\n')

            data = ''
            buf = s.recv(1024)
            while len(buf):
                data += buf
                buf = s.recv(1024)
            s.close()

            file = open('./whois_records/'+domain, 'w')
            file.write(data)
            file.close()

#           if domain.lower() not in data.lower():
#               raise Exception(domain, 'Domain not found in WHOIS: '+data)
#               continue

            if str(domain).lower() in str(data).lower():
                obj = WhoisEntry.load(domain, data)
                logger.debug('WHOIS success ' + domain + ': ' + str(data))
               return {
                            'expiration_date':  str(obj.expiration_date),
                            'status':           str(obj.status),
                            'registrar':        str(obj.registrar)
                       }
        except Exception, e:
            logger.error('WHOIS Lookup Failed: '+str(e))
    return None
```